# Where is the photo for the outlook sign in page taken?

Tags: identify-this, photography

I would like to know where the photo of the Outlook.com sign in page was taken. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is Rio de Janeiro, Brazil, taken from the statue of [Christ the Redeemer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christ_the_Redeemer_(statue)). Here's a similar view from Google Earth:

[image]